# Logitech webcam USB C Windows

Tags: c, windows, camera, usb

I would like to basically just grab frames from a Logitech USB camera.  How does one go about doing this?  I could send it USB instructions; however, I don't think Logitech has a document with the instructions needed to control the camera.  Is the way to do it using the Direct Show?  The Windows MPD seemed like a good idea, but I Don't think Logitech devices support it.  What is the standard way to communicate with a USB camera?

Thanks.